# Windows batch file: defining variables from a file inside a for loop

Tags: batch-file

Why is it that the following gives the output I expect:

```
@echo off

echo foobar > tmp.txt

SET /P a= < tmp.txt
echo %a%

FOR /F %%Q IN (tmp.txt) do set b=%%Q
echo %b%
```

i.e.,

`foobar
foobar`

While the following does not:

```
@echo off
FOR /L %%n in (1,1,1) DO (
    echo foobar > tmp.txt

    SET /P a= < tmp.txt
    echo %a%

    FOR /F %%Q IN (tmp.txt) do set b=%%Q
    echo %b%
)
```

i.e.,

```
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

Everything I can find gives direction for how to do things outside the `loop` environment.

---

Answer with guidance from David Ruhmann

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /L %%n in (1,1,1) DO (
    echo foobar > tmp.txt

    SET /P a= < tmp.txt
    echo !a!

    FOR /F %%Q IN (tmp.txt) do set b=%%Q
    echo !b!
)
```

Comment: You need to use **delayed expansion** for the variables. See [`setlocal /?`](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) and [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Or [Search StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+delayed+expansion)

Comment: Thank you! I don't have enough reputation to fill in the answer below, but you gave me all I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "ECHO is off" response shows that echo did not 'see' any command line entries.

In the failling example, you aren't using the resulting "n" from **%%n** in the first **FOR** loop, and are you sure that **in (1,1,1)** actually runs through the loop once?

-- after edits --

So the "ECHO is off" proves that it does run through the loop once. So I don't see a specific flaw with the code.  This leads me to exercise my Google-fu:

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php

Hope that helps.

Comment: I didn't use `%%n` as I was trying to simplify the example. In my actual script, I am using `%%n` to run a script that updates the contents of `tmp.txt`, which I then need to read into my batch file.